# vb.net offline and DBdatabase online. How to connect

Tags: database, vb.net

I have not found enough information about this online but I am sure that is possible. I want to have a vb.net application in my computer and connect to a database in my hosting to add records.
Also, I want to access the database online to see those records from away from home. Kind of like having my own phone book online in my hosting..

Can someone point me in the right direction.
1. Do I use access or mysql?
2. Do I set up the connection string using a ftp or something different?
3. I want to develop in asp.net

Thanks to all

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the instructions on how to post questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help). In particular, please post the relevant part of your implementation that demonstrates the issue you need help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Access is probably not a good fit, as it is not really reliable across an Internet connection, so I would go with MySQL. Unless you want to consider SQL Server, which has better out-of-the-box support in Visual Studio.
2. For a server-based database (MySQL or SQL Server), your connection string will include the server address provided by your host and possibly a port. If you insist on using a file-based database (Access or SQL Server CE), the database will probably be on a shared folder on the host, and the connection string will include the path to that shared folder.
3. If you are developing in ASP.NET, your host may limit your choice of database.